# How to remove through table attributes?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have four models:

```
Category
Video
VideoCategory
VideoSchedule
```

With these relationships:

```js
Category.belongsToMany(Video, { through: VideoCategory })
Video.belongsToMany(Category, { through: VideoCategory })
Video.hasOne(VideoSchedule)
VideoSchedule.belongsTo(Video)
```

I want to retrieve a list of categories for currently scheduled videos. I am very close, but Sequelize keeps giving me the attributes from the through table when all I want is the `Category.id` and `Category.name`. Here is my Sequelize:

```js
Category.findAll({ 
  attributes: ['id', 'name'], 
  raw: true, 
  group: 'Category.id', 
  order: 'Category.name', 
  include: [
    { 
      model: Video, 
      attributes: [], 
      where: { active: true }, 
      through: { attributes: [] }, 
      include: [
        { 
          model: 
          VideoSchedule, 
          attributes: [], 
          where: { site_id: 106 }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}).then(function(cats) { console.log(cats); } );
```

Here's a sample of the output I am getting:

```js
{ id: 1,
  name: 'Comedy',
  'Videos.VideoCategory.category_id': 1,
  'Videos.VideoCategory.video_id': 962 },
{ id: 2,
  name: 'Drama',
  'Videos.VideoCategory.category_id': 2,
  'Videos.VideoCategory.video_id': 914 }
```

What I really want is just `{ id: 1, name: 'Comedy' }, { id: 2, name: 'Drama'}`. How do I get rid of the extra attributes from the through table? I tried using `through: { attributes: [] }` in my `include` statement, but to no avail. Just to be thorough, here is the SQL statement generated by Sequelize:

```js
SELECT 
`Category`.`id`, 
`Category`.`name`, 
`Videos.VideoCategory`.`category_id` AS `Videos.VideoCategory.category_id`, 
`Videos.VideoCategory`.`video_id` AS `Videos.VideoCategory.video_id` 
FROM 
`categories` AS `Category` 
INNER JOIN (`video_categories` AS `Videos.VideoCategory` 
  INNER JOIN `videos` AS `Videos` ON `Videos`.`id` = `Videos.VideoCategory`.`video_id`) 
ON `Category`.`id` = `Videos.VideoCategory`.`category_id` 
AND `Videos`.`active` = true 
INNER JOIN `video_schedules` AS `Videos.VideoSchedule` 
ON `Videos`.`id` = `Videos.VideoSchedule`.`video_id` 
AND `Videos.VideoSchedule`.`site_id` = 106 
GROUP BY Category.id 
ORDER BY Category.name;
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this, this is a bug in Sequelize. Looks like it will be fixed in 4.x, but not 3.x.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5590

Comment: There are also comments about this issue in https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/6297 Especially if you want to include only some attributes from the through table, and if you want the sql query to reflect those restrictions, `through: { attributes: ['foobar'] }` will not work.